# Where can I get little durable cases you can hang on your climbing harness?

Tags: gear, climbing, gear-care

On longer climbing sessions I like to keep my cell phone close by, but most of the time I have no backpack with me. So I would like to pack the cell phone in a little case that I can put on my climbing harness via a carabiner.

I know some case manufactures that do provide durable small cases, but none with a loop to put your carabiner through.

As it can get pretty rough in the wall, I like this box being **durable** since it needs to protect my stuff.

What box does work well and has proven to withstand harsh conditions?

Consider that I do not want to wear clothes with pockets.

Comment: I swear my son’s APRS transmitter is stuffed in a small yellow Pelican case thing, with a biner attached... I’ll look later this week.

Comment: Something like https://www.rei.com/product/778218/pelican-1060-case-with-carabiner ?

Comment: Jon, thank you very much! 

But please nothing like this particlar case by Pelican. The case and the esp. the flimsy biner there is not robust at all. I want something I could hang 10kg on. At least. But now I know, that one manufacturer is called Pelican. This is helpful!

Comment: This is something I like! https://www.pelican.com/us/en/product/cases/go-case/personal-utility/g10

Comment: I use a regular phone case with a [PopSocket](https://www.popsockets.com/) [Gorilla Glued](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/original-gorilla-glue/) to the back, and tie a piece of elastic cord around it with a [mooring hitch](https://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/mooring-hitch), which is also connected to my pants.

Comment: @endolith - Do not trust polyurethane style adhesives (i.e. Gorilla brand) to anything that is not porous, including most plastics, where any sort of torsion forces are involved.  I've cleaned the stuff off PVC just by lightly flexing- it peels right off.

Comment: Why does it need to be able to carry 10kgs? what kind of phone are you using!?

Comment: Just stick it in a ziplock bag and then put it in your chalk bag or put it in your pocket.

Comment: Ok, try something like https://www.rei.com/product/150749/pelican-go-g40-case - a search on REI’s site for Pelican cases brings up a variety- this one you add your own carabiner to...

Comment: @cobaltduck I've been using it for a while and it works ok. It did eventually come off, but it was a very slow peel over weeks so I knew when it was loose and re-glued it.  The case is TPE I think, and the popsocket is polycarbonate?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LLRTGxp.jpg

Comment: one of the waterproof hard plastic cases could work they make them phone sized and many have a loop or biner attachment

Answer (score 5):

One possibility:  Check out the home improvement store.  Check the tool section.  You can get all sorts of attachments for tool belts, including ones to carry things like a cell phone.

They aren't rigid.  If rock climbing I'd use this and something like an Otter Case to protect the phone itself.  They don't have a ring for a 'biner, but they do have a loop for belt or web sling.  You may need to comb out the velcro now and then to get it to secure the flap properly.

Here's 3 from Lowes.  [image]

Also:  the phone itself should have a case or skin that is a bright colour.  I read a post on a hiking forum of someone having dropped their phone on some loop trail and were asking for people to keep an eye out for it.  Finding a black rectangle on a trail with lots of basalt (dark grey) rocks. I have a hot pink skin on my iPhone that has helped me find it several times.

*If you don't have pockets or a backpack, how do you carry lunch, snacks, a windbreaker for when you're on belay...?*

Answer (score 2):

Pelican makes small cases for electronics.  There is likely something of a size to do what you want.